# How to get matlab to read a txt file with image names and populate an array?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, input

My objective here is to read from a text file filenames for images as strings, EX: myImage.jpg.

I have this block of code that reads how many lines are in the file.

```
listOfImages = fopen('translate.txt', 'r');
count = 0;
%This while loop calculates the amount of lines within our text file
while ~feof(listOfImages)
    line = fgetl(listOfImages);
    if isempty(line) | strncmp(line, '%', 1)
       continue
    end
    count = count+1;
end
numberOfLines = count;
```

now using numberOfLines how do i put each line into some sort of array of strings using a for loop.

so,

```
for i = 1:numberOfLines,
    DO CODE
end
```

what do i put here to make it so i can read my translate.txt file row by row?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the file names will likely be different lengths you will want to use a cell instead of a matrix.

Try the following:

```
% read the text into names, breaking on newlines
fid = fopen('translate.txt');
names = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
names = names{1};
fclose(fid);

for f = 1:length(names)
    disp(names(f));
end
```